# Google Admob test ads do not work after deploying to Play store

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob

3 weeks ago I deployed my Unity Android game to Google Play Store. I registered my phone as a test device and tested if the ads worked both by using google's own test ids and my own ad ids. Everything worked fine. A week later, I realized that the ads did not work when I tried to build a newer version of my app even when I enter the test ids. Building an older version that used to work and building onto a different device did not work either. Logcat shows "**ad failed to load : 3**" when I run the app. I have also checked my app id at least 10 times so I know that is not the problem either.

As of today, I also received a message in my admob account telling me that my ad serving has been limited. I don't know why they have done this given that I never received a real ad on my devices and I always used test ads. I thought maybe the limited account is the problem but the problem has existed for 2 weeks whereas my account has been limited for a couple hours. It also does not explain why I wouldn't receive ads when I enter test ids. If it will help, my test device is a Xiomi Redmi device which I know has certain issues with Unity apps such as push notifications though I doubt that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

according to some User of admob the limits will stay for more then 6 months or if you can get 2500 to 3000 new organic user of the whole account of admob